# Using AVERAGE in a INDEX, MATCH formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have two sheets, **Ingredient** and **Product**. I want **Product's** `Food Cost` cell to be the AVERAGE of **Ingredient's** `Unit Cost` values, but only average the ones with the matching code of 101.

Here is my Ingredient Sheet.

[image: Ingredient Sheet]

Here is my Product Sheet.

[image: My Product Sheet]

This is the formula I came up with, which would show only one value if my **Ingredient Sheet** had only entries with the Code 101, how can I populate food cost with the AVERAGE `Unit Cost` of only the ones with the code 101. I can't figure where to fit AVERAGE into this formula to make it work.

=$C2*INDEX(Ingredient!$C2:$C5, MATCH($B2,Ingredient!$B5:$B5, 0))

Comment: Use [`AVERAGEIFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690): `=C2*AVERAGEIFS(Ingredient!$C2:$C5,Ingredient!$B5:$B5,$B2)`

Comment: It works after changing the first $B5 to $B1. Thank you.